# Why can't WSGI configuration file find my Python variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I am trying to setup [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) with a simple Python app but the WSGI config doesn't seem to be able to import properly, what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import web
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom

... [code] ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
    #app.wsgifunc()
```

and my WSGI is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys

path = "/home/myUsername"
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from myPythonFileNameInSameDir import app as application
application.wsgifunc()
```

Comment: `__name__` is equal to "main" only if the python script is being executed directly.   If you're importing it, then `__name__` isn't "main", therefore `app` does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here -- when you import your web.py app from the WSGI file, it won't run anything in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` section.

You need to do this in the app:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import web
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom

... [code] ...

app = web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

...and this in the WSGI file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys

path = "/home/myUsername"
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from myPythonFileNameInSameDir import app
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

Comment: Excellent! All makes sense now. Thank you